USB to RS485 Module with MODBUS-RTU RS485 Soil Sensor on Raspberry Pi 4B
If I purchase 2 of the USB to RS485 Module from DFRobot (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2189.html) and 2 types of soil sensors which require that USB converter (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2819.html) + (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2818.html), then can I use both on the Raspberry Pi 4B as it has 4 USB ports? And how do I set up the sensors with this USB converter for the Raspberry Pi 4B?

There is some example Arduino code (hanging off your second link in the "Product Wiki") which doesn't use any (special) libraries, so it wouldn't be to hard to derive your code from that example, nor to port to Python if that is your target language (you don't specify which language you intend to use).
